# Veto algorithm in particle decays and Monte Carlo techniques

Tags: particle-physics, computational-physics, statistics, beyond-the-standard-model, algorithms

What is the main concept behind [Veto algorithm](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=veto+algorithm) and how does it contribute to efficiency in Monte Carlo methods like when used in designing a parton shower?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veto algorithm is an efficient way to integrate invertible functions or any functions for that matter. What Veto algorithm does is that it uses a separate function(over-estimating function) such that we do not need to use the original function's inverse or its integral.

Mathematically, if $ f(t)$ is the function to be integrated, with no simple $F(t)$ or $F(t)^{-1}$ where $F(t)$ is the integral of $f(t)$, then we use the over-estimating function $G(t)$ to find the probability distribution $P(t)$ of $f(t)$. So we have $P(t) = f(t) \exp(-\int_0^t dt' g(t'))$, where $g(t)$ is $\frac{d}{dt}G(t) = g(t)$.

For its use in a parton shower evolution, we can refer to how it uses the entire phase space available avoiding double counting. We follow the same method as stated in the first paragraph and then, in the end, it eliminates the over-estimated region of phase space by multiplying the reciprocal of the over-estimated function. For further reading of veto algorithm in parton showers, see section 3.2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.4085) and slides 54 onwards of [these slides](http://home.thep.lu.se/%7Etorbjorn/ppp2018/lec1.pdf).